# Regex expression for extracting SQL Server function value

Tags: c#, .net, regex

All,

I need regex expression (c#) for extracting a SQL server getdate function expression from the parentheses that SQL server wraps around everything. Best is explained using an example (note, you can have +/- for the operator):

SQL server expression: (getdate()+(1))

My desired result: getdate()+1

So far I have this, but it is not quite right:

```
\((getdate\(\)(\+|\-)\(?\d\)?)\)
```

ADDED:

This one will work by creating 3 groups, after which I can combine them together to get entire expression. Is there a better solution?

```
\((getdate\(\))(\+|\-)\(?(\d+)\)?\)
```

Comment: I removed the white-spaces to avoid confusion.

Comment: Your use of `{1}` is unnecessary and can be removed - each previous item will be matched a single time only anyway.

Comment: Overall though it's a bit unclear what you're asking - the second regex you've added [appears to extract](https://regex101.com/r/tD2gR3/1) the parts you're interested in?

Comment: To clarify: I can use groupings to build the entire resultant value after match is done (which is my 2nd expression), or preferably match a value and get the value back without any surrounding parenthesis (preferred).

Comment: Don't use capture parenthesis around constants, they're already known. Don't use alternations for single characters, use a class. Result - `\(getdate\(\)([+-])\(?(\d+)\)?\)`

Comment: I did this on purpose  so hat I can extract the correct tokens w/ out the parentheses. Your expr. retains the parentheses I am trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\((getdate\(\))(\+|\-)\(?(\d+)\)?\)
```

Gives me the result after combining the 3 captured groups. I am sure there's better solution where you can consume the unwanted parentheses and have a single value returned.